# Using Moivre-Laplace, how to reduce $\phi$

Tags: probability, probability-theory, laplace-method

> Estimate the probability such that if 2 coins are thrown at the same time, for 100 times, "heads" to appear a number of times in between $15$ and $20$.

I considered $X_k= \begin{pmatrix}0&1\\0.5&0.5\end{pmatrix}$  so $M[X_k]=0.5$ and $\sigma=0.25$, rather than considering $2$ same events at the same time i thought it's the same to consider the same event twice the number of throwns so $n = 200$.

Then 
$$P(15 \leq X_k\leq 20)= \Phi(\frac {20 - 200\times0.5}{\sqrt{200\times0.5\times 0.5}}) - \Phi(\frac {15 - 200\times0.5}{\sqrt{200\times0.5\times 0.5}})=\Phi(12.14)-\Phi(11.42)$$

But these values are not in the table and the tables goes up to $3.5$ how to make them be in the table? How do i proceed?

Comment: Have you noticed that $\frac{20 - 200*0.5}{\sqrt{200*0.5* 0.5}}=-11.3137$?

Comment: @callculus definetely

Comment: I had doubts since neither you nor Ekesh Kumar has mentioned it.

Comment: @callculus that's not the point of the question anyway

Comment: Don´t be so rude. In math calculation does always matter. Btw, maybe other things are wrong as well. But I´m not willing to check it.

Comment: Not sure I understand the question.  Why are you flipping two coins at once?  Why is "heads" in quotation marks?  Are you sure they mean the same thing as throwing a single coin $200$ times?  Anyway, It's not especially difficult to compute the probability exactly.  Easier than using the normal approximation, I'd say.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want a very accurate value, you can use a calculator's $\verb!normalcdf!$ function, or find something similar online. However, note that $\Phi(12.14) \approx 1$ and $\Phi(11.42) \approx 1$, meaning that the probability that $X_{k}$ lies between $15$ and $20$ will be about zero.

This makes sense intuitively because it's very unlikely to only get between $15$ and $20$ heads if you're flipping $200$ coins.

Comment: So there is no way to reduce that value?

Comment: You can reduce the value. The "exact" value of the $\Phi$ function comes from an integral over the normal cumulative distribution function. So, you can work with those if you'd like. (However, even this would be an approximation. Probabilities computed using Moivre-Laplace are all approximations).